# How to broken jvm parameter count limit?

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments, thrift-protocol

My project use thrift service but it can't allow generate more then 254 APIs.
With the compile error:

```
Platform restriction: a parameter list's length cannot exceed 254.
```

It seems jvm not allow over 254 parameter. How to broken the limit ? thanks